# Render a new page on react-routing but it renders it inside the current page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This displays a card component that the user sees if the user clicks the `<Link>read</Link>` it should re-render a new page.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./CardComponent.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Content from "./ContentFolder/Content";

function CardComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div class="card">
        <div className="uppercard">
          <img
            className="bookCover"
            src={props.img}
            alt=""
            width="120px"
            height="150px"
          />
          <h3>{props.title}</h3>

          <h6>By{props.author}</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="lowerCard">{props.points}</div>
        <Link to={"/" + props.title + props.author}>Read</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`/${props.title+props.author}`}
          component={Content}
        >
          <Content title={props.title} author={props.author}
            points={props.points}
          />
          
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default CardComponent;
```

On clicking read I want to render this content component on a different page.

In summary, the goal is to display all the information on a new page when the user clicks on one of the card components.

```
import React from "react";
import Mynavbar from "../Partials/Mynavbar";
import MyFooter from "../Partials/Footer";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Content.css";

function Content(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Mynavbar />
      <Container className="main">
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
        <h6>By {props.author}</h6>
         <ul>
          {props.points.map((point, i) => {
            return <li>{point}</li>;
          })}
        </ul> 
      </Container>
      <MyFooter />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Content;
```

Comment: Everything outside of the Switch will be rendered on every page.

Comment: Now it doesn't render on the same page but not on a different page too. Only the URL changes above nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem: `Router` inside of `CardComponent`

The `Router` needs to exist at the highest level of the `App`.  Everything that is inside of the `Router` and outside of the `Switch` will be rendered on every page.  So right now your card code will show up even on the `Content` route.  We want the `Card` and the `Content` to be separate `Route`s.

#### Problem: Ambiguous URL Structure

Do you *need* for your urls to look like `"/${props.title+props.author}"`?  This is a very bad structure because you cannot possibly work backwards from the URL to the content.  What is the content for `"/Harry PotterJ.K. Rowling"`?  Which part is the title and which part is the author?  There is no separator so you don't know.  You would have to loop through a list of all books, joining their title and author and comparing it to your string.

A typical URL would be based on an `id`, like `"/book/5"`. I don't see any mention of an id here so we can use the `title`.

#### Solution

An app routing might look like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/book/:title" component={BookDetails}/>
        <Route path="/" component={BookList}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Let's get rid of all the routing in `CardComponent` and make it just show a card for a book with a link to the book details.

```
function CardComponent(props: Book) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="uppercard">
        <img
          className="bookCover"
          src={props.img}
          alt=""
          width="120px"
          height="150px"
        />
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>

        <h6>By{props.author}</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="lowerCard">{props.points}</div>
      <Link to={"/book/" + props.title}>Read</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Our home page might show a list of these cards.

```
function BookList() {
  // get books from somewhere -- a database? a json file?
  const books = ???;

  return (
    <ul className="bookList">
      {books.map((book) => (
        <CardComponent {...book} key={book.title} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

`BookDetails` is a separate route, so we need to get the book from the URL.

```
function BookDetails(props: RouteComponentProps) {
  // get the title from the URL
  // is automatically encoded and needs to be decoded
  const title = decodeURIComponent(props.match.params.title);
  // find the book object from your data source
  const book = ???
  // from a JSON array: BOOKS.find(book => book.title.toLowerCase() === title.toLowerCase() );

  // redirect to error page if no matching book
  if ( ! book ) {
    return <Redirect to="/404" />
  }

  // can render your Content component, but only after we get the book
  return (
    <Content {...book} />
  )
}
```